# TreeSet.contains() does not call overwritten equals

Tags: java, treeset

i have a problem with the contains() method of TreeSet. As I understand it, contains() should call equals() of the contained Objects as the javadoc says:

> **boolean java.util.TreeSet.contains(Object o)**: Returns true if this set
>   contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and
>   only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e)).

What I try to do:
I have a list of TreeSets with Result Objects that have a member `String baseword`. Now I want to compare each TreeSet with all Others, and make for each pair a list of basewords they share. For this, I iterate over the list once for a `treeSet1` and a second time for a `treeSet2`, then I iterate over all ResultObjects in `treeSet2` and run `treeSet1.contains(ResultObject)` for each, to see if `treeSet1` contains a Result Object with this wordbase. I adjusted the `compareTo` and `equals` methods of the ResultObject. But it seems that my `equals` is never called.
Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work?

Greetings,
Daniel

```
    public static void getIntersection(ArrayList<TreeSet<Result>> list, int value){

          for (TreeSet<Result> treeSet : list){

    //for each treeSet, we iterate again through the list of TreeSet, starting at the TreeSet that is next
                //to the one we got in the outer loop
                for (TreeSet<Result> treeSet2 : list.subList((list.indexOf(treeSet))+1, list.size())){

                //so at this point, we got 2 different TreeSets 
                HashSet<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>();

                for (Result result : treeSet){  
                    //we iterate over each result in the first treeSet and see if the wordbase exists also in the second one                

//!!!
                    if (treeSet2.contains(result)){
                        intersection.add(result.wordbase);
                    }
                }
                if (!intersection.isEmpty()){
                    intersections.add(intersection);
                }
            }
        }


public class Result implements Comparable<Result>{

    public Result(String wordbase, double result[]){
        this.result = result;
        this.wordbase = wordbase;
    }

    public String wordbase;
    public double[] result;

    public int compareTo(DifferenceAnalysisResult o) {

        if (o == null) return 0;

        return this.wordbase.compareTo(o.wordbase);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((wordbase == null) ? 0 : wordbase.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

//never called
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DifferenceAnalysisResult other = (DifferenceAnalysisResult) obj;
        if (wordbase == null) {
            if (other.wordbase != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!wordbase.equals(other.wordbase))
            return false;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Equals is only called (if ever) when the proper branch in the tree is found via `compareTo` .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> As I understand it, contains() should call equals() of the contained Objects

Not for [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), no. It calls `compare`:

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. **The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.**
>
> ...
>
> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if it is to correctly implement the Set interface.

Your `compareTo` method isn't currently consistent with `equals` - `x.compareTo(null)` returns 0, whereas `x.equals(null)` returns false. Maybe you're okay with that, but you shouldn't expect `equals` to be called.